# Using Python3: Getting API Error: 400 Bad Request; Status : INVALID_ARGUMENT

Tags: python-3.x, google-api

Using Python3  to access Google's API, specifically Tag Manager v2; I want to batch delete specific triggers. I get 400 Bad Request: INVALID_ARGUMENT. I need help to understand what is invalid with the value I'm passing to the API command.

Using Pythn3.7, using PyCharm CE, I connect successfully using OAuth 2.0 via Chrome(Version 76.0.3809.132 (Official Build) (64-bit)), I allow GTM access and Google authenticates me with success, a tagmanager.dat file is created. The intent is to batch delete Triggers based on a regex pattern. 
NOTE: I am on a basic Console Developers account. I understand the quota limits and my code accounts for those limits.

What I've done:

1. Re-evaluate my logic and have a fellow developer take a look; he didn't notice anything out of order with my logic
2. Using PyCharm's debug to step through, the debugger didn't display any error messages
3. Used the code I used to batch delete Tags, which was 100% successful, but changed it for Triggers and I get 400: Bad Request: INVALID_ARGUMENT
4. Deleted tagmanager.dat file and then reauthenticate
5. Closed PyCharm CE and restarted it
6. Turn my computer off and on again

```
getContainerPath = ''
getTriggerName = ''
getAMSIAccount = service.accounts().list().execute()['account'][0]['path']
getAMSIContainers = service.accounts().containers().list(parent=getAMSIAccount).execute()['container']
gtmTriggerErrorHandling = open('gtmTriggerErrorHandling.txt','w')
queries = 2
for container in getAMSIContainers:
    queries += 1
    print(str(queries) + ' ###### ' + container['name'])
    if queries >= 24:
        time.sleep(101)
        queries = 1
    elif queries < 24:
        print(str(queries) + ' | ' + container['name'] + ' | ' + container['containerId'] + ' | ' + container['publicId'])
        getContainerPath = container['path']
        getAMSIWorkspace = service.accounts().containers().workspaces().list(parent=getContainerPath).execute()['workspace'][0]
        getAMSIWorkspacePath = getAMSIWorkspace['path']
        getAMSITriggers = service.accounts().containers().workspaces().triggers().list(parent=getAMSIWorkspacePath).execute()['trigger']
        queries += 2
        for trigger in getAMSITriggers:
            print(str(queries) + ': ' + trigger['name'])
            getTriggerName = re.search(r'Event - [Dd][Oo] - ([Ss][Rr][Pp]|[Vv][Dd][Pp]) - ([Nn][Ee][Ww]|[Uu][Ss][Ee][Dd]).*', trigger['name'])
            getTriggerIgnore = re.search(r'^Event - DO - (SRP|VDP) - (New|Used) - Regex Table$', trigger['name'])
            if not getTriggerName:
                continue
            elif queries < 24 and getTriggerName and not getTriggerIgnore:
                getTriggerPath = trigger['path']
                print(getTriggerPath)
                try:
                    service.accounts().containers().workspaces().triggers().delete(path=getTriggerPath).execute()
                except HttpError as error:
                    gtmTriggerErrorHandling.write('There was an API error : %s : %s : %s : %s : %s' %(error.resp.status, error.resp.reason, error.uri, error.error_details, error.content) + '\n')
                queries += 1
            elif queries >= 24:
                time.sleep(101)
                queries = 1
            else:
                continue
```

Here's the error output:

```
There was an API error : 400 : Bad Request : https://www.googleapis.com/tagmanager/v2/accounts/256581/containers/460206/workspaces/494/triggers/446? :  : b'{\n  "error": {\n    "code": 400,\n    "message": "Returned an error response for your request.",\n    "errors": [\n      {\n        "message": "Returned an error response for your request.",\n        "domain": "global",\n        "reason": "badRequest"\n      }\n    ],\n    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"\n  }\n}\n'
There was an API error : 400 : Bad Request : https://www.googleapis.com/tagmanager/v2/accounts/256581/containers/460206/workspaces/494/triggers/447? :  : b'{\n  "error": {\n    "code": 400,\n    "message": "Returned an error response for your request.",\n    "errors": [\n      {\n        "message": "Returned an error response for your request.",\n        "domain": "global",\n        "reason": "badRequest"\n      }\n    ],\n    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"\n  }\n}\n'
There was an API error : 400 : Bad Request : https://www.googleapis.com/tagmanager/v2/accounts/256581/containers/460206/workspaces/494/triggers/448? :  : b'{\n  "error": {\n    "code": 400,\n    "message": "Returned an error response for your request.",\n    "errors": [\n      {\n        "message": "Returned an error response for your request.",\n        "domain": "global",\n        "reason": "badRequest"\n      }\n    ],\n    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"\n  }\n}\n'
There was an API error : 400 : Bad Request : https://www.googleapis.com/tagmanager/v2/accounts/256581/containers/460206/workspaces/494/triggers/449? :  : b'{\n  "error": {\n    "code": 400,\n    "message": "Returned an error response for your request.",\n    "errors": [\n      {\n        "message": "Returned an error response for your request.",\n        "domain": "global",\n        "reason": "badRequest"\n      }\n    ],\n    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"\n  }\n}\n'
```

These four images demonstrate that these triggers exist in the container. See the status message at the bottom of each image and it will match up with each error above.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pujdj.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaJaU.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuCU7.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bN8wh.png

The expectation is, based on the regex, these triggers get placed under "Workspace Changes" found in the "Overview" when using GTM GUI.

Thank you for any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was very simple and right in front of me. The triggers I am trying to delete are still associated with a Tag. The is the reason for the error messages. The API, logically and correctly won't delete a Trigger as long as it's associated with a Tag.